# How to make an HTTP hook reusable on the same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an HTTP hook that can be consumed like this:

```
const { data, error, isLoading, executeFetch } = useHttp<IArticle[]>('news', []);
```

In the same component, I want to trigger another API call to POST data and update one of the articles:

```
const handleChange = (article: IArticle, event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        executeFetch(`updateNews?id=${article.id}`, { method: 'post', data: { isRead: event.target.checked }});
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className={classes.articleListHeader}>
                <h1>Article List</h1>
                <small className={classes.headerSubtitle}>{data.length} Articles</small>
            </div>
            <ul>
                {data.map(article => <Article key={article.id} article={article} handleChange={handleChange}/>)}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
```

My custom hook to fetch data:

```
export function useHttp<T>(initUrl: string, initData: T): UseHttp<T> {
    const initOptions: AxiosRequestConfig = { url: initUrl };

    const [options, setOptions] = useState(initOptions);

    const useHttpReducer = createHttpReducer<T>();
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(useHttpReducer, {
        isLoading: false,
        error: '',
        data: initData
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        let cancelRequest = false;

        const fetchData = async (cancelRequest: boolean = false) => {
            if (!options.url) return;

            dispatch({ type: API_REQUEST});
            try {
                const responsePromise: AxiosPromise<T> = axios(options);
                const response = await responsePromise;
                if (cancelRequest) return;
                dispatch({ type: API_SUCCESS, payload: response.data });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("Got error", e);
                dispatch({ type: API_ERROR, payload: e.message });
            }
        };
        fetchData(cancelRequest);

        return () => {
            cancelRequest = true;
        }

    }, [options]);

    const executeFetch = (url: string, options: AxiosRequestConfig = axiosInitialOptions): void => {
        options.url = url;
        setOptions(options);
    };


    return { ...state, executeFetch}
```

The issue is, when I'm doing something like this, the `data` replaces to the new response (of the `POST` request), then my UI crashes (no more article list..)

What's the good practice to manage situations like this when I need to call another API in the same component while keeping the reusability of my HTTP hook?

I simply want to execute a POST request somewhere in the component after my GET one - How I can do it in a reusable way and fix my issue?

Comment: Not sure if this will help but did you check the [useSWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) by Vercel?

Comment: Thanks but I would like to learn :D

Comment: Is `executeFetch` a function defined inside the component? If yes, can you add its implementation? Right now, I don't see why the value of `data` would change.

Comment: @Eldraxm the `executeFetch` function is returned from the useHttp hook.

Comment: you can rename the return values of data in the two calls . Example : 
const { data: firstAPICall, error: firstError } = useHttp<IArticle[]>('news', []);
const { data: secondAPICall, error: secondError} = useHttp<IArticle[]>('news', []);

Answer (score 0):

You can refactoring your custom hook to receive a callback function. I omitted the part of `cancelRequest`, if you are using `axios` you can cancel the request via `CancelToken`:

```
export function useHttp<T>(initUrl: string): UseHttp<T> {
   const initOptions: AxiosRequestConfig = { url: initUrl };

   const [options, setOptions] = useState(initOptions);

   const useHttpReducer = createHttpReducer<T>();
   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(useHttpReducer, {
      isLoading: false,
      error: '',
   });

   const fetchData = async (options, callback) => {
      if (!options.url) return;
      dispatch({ type: API_REQUEST});
      try {
         const responsePromise: AxiosPromise<T> = axios(options);
         const response = await responsePromise;
         dispatch({ type: API_SUCCESS, payload: response.data });
         callback(response.data);
      } catch (e) {
         console.log("Got error", e);
         dispatch({ type: API_ERROR, payload: e.message });
      }
   };

   const executeFetch = (url: string, requestOptions: AxiosRequestConfig = axiosInitialOptions, callback): void => {
      options.url = url;
      fetchData({...options, ...requestOptions}, callback);
   };

   return { ...state, executeFetch}
};
```

**Usage:**

```
const [articles, setArticles]= useState();
const { error, isLoading, executeFetch } = useHttpRequest();


const handleChange = (article: IArticle, event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
   executeFetch(`updateNews?id=${article.id}`, { method: 'post', data: { isRead: event.target.checked }}, setArticles);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a great idea!! Any chance to share how it can be used with my custom hook - I already have one that i'm using, I posted the code. I tried to add the callback logic with no luck.

Comment: I updated my answer, it is just an idea, I didn't test it, I hope this can help you